# Why this custom dictionary class is not working - C# 4.0

Tags: c#, class, c#-4.0, dictionary, custom-attributes

I am writing a custom dictionary class for my task but it is giving error. What is the problem at this class ? Thank you

```
        public struct MyValue
    {
        public int irValue1;
        public int irValue2;
    }

    public class csCustomDictionary : Dictionary<string, MyValue>
    {
        public void Add(string srKey, int irVal1, int irVal2)
        {
            if (this.ContainsKey(srKey) == true)
            {
                this[srKey].irValue1 = this[srKey].irValue1 + irVal1;
                this[srKey].irValue1 = this[srKey].irValue2 + irVal2;
            }
            else
            {
                MyValue val;
                val.irValue1 = irVal1;
                val.irValue2 = irVal2;
                this.Add(srKey, val);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is the error message

[image]

C# 4.0

***Is this modified version correct***

```
    public class csMyValue
{
    public int irValue1;
    public int irValue2;
}

public class csCustomDictionary : Dictionary<string, csMyValue>
{
    public void Add(string srKey, int irVal1, int irVal2)
    {
        if (this.ContainsKey(srKey) == true)
        {
            this[srKey].irValue1 = this[srKey].irValue1 + irVal1;
            this[srKey].irValue1 = this[srKey].irValue2 + irVal2;
        }
        else
        {
            csMyValue val = new csMyValue();
            val.irValue1 = irVal1;
            val.irValue2 = irVal2;
            this.Add(srKey, val);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *What* error? Where is it? Do you get an exception? Does it not perform as expected? Don't make us be detectives.

Comment: Added error image. Please refresh and recheck

Comment: Did you know that you can just click the error and press F1 to get this help page? [Compiler Error CS1612](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wydkhw2c(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a `struct` as your Value in the Dictionary.

When you write: `this[srKey]`, you actually retrieve a *copy of the struct* stored as the Dictionary's value.  As such, the `.irValue1` is trying to set a field on the copy (that will soon disappear).

If you change `MyValue` to be a class, this should work.  This is more appropriate, as well, as you're making a *mutable type*, and mutable structs are very rarely a good idea.

That being said, you could force this to work via making a temporary, setting the fields, *then* setting the value in your Dictionary:

```
if (this.ContainsKey(srKey) == true)
{
    MyValue tmp = this[srKey];
    tmp.irValue1 += irVal1;
    tmp.irValue2 += irVal2;
    this[srKey] = tmp;
}
```

If you change `MyValue` to be a class instead of a struct, you could write:

```
    MyValue tmp = this[srKey];
    tmp.irValue1 += irVal1;
    tmp.irValue2 += irVal2;
```

Since the stored value would be a reference, this will do the change that you wish without requiring lots of dictionary lookups.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I modified the question and added class version. Would that work well ? or are there any better approach ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG The class version will work - but read my last section ;)  It shows a better version using the class (get a tmp, increment), as it won't have to do the dictionary lookup 4 times, just once.

Comment: So instead of if statement i will just use your version right ? Or just replace the inside of if checking ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG That goes inside of the if statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help Reed Copsey. Found out that with trying :)

Comment: Not that the line `this[srKey] = tmp` is not needed, as there's only one copy of the object in memory, so doing `tmp.irValue1 += irVal1` is already changing the object within the dictionary.

Comment: @Diego With `MyValue` being a *struct*, as written in the original question, this is not true.   `tmp` is a **copy** of the struct stored in the dictionary, so you must set the values in the copy, then set the entire struct (which copies it back into the dictionary entry).  That was the entire cause of the original error.  If you note, at the end, I mention that this is not needed when using a class.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's saying `this[whatever]` cannot be in the left-hand-side of an assignment. Try this:

```
public class csCustomDictionary : Dictionary<string, MyValue>
{
    public void Add(string srKey, int irVal1, int irVal2)
    {
        if (this.ContainsKey(srKey) == true)
        {
            var myVal = this[srKey];
            myVal.irValue1 = myVal.irValue1 + irVal1;
            myVal.irValue1 = myVal.irValue2 + irVal2;
        }
        else
        {
            MyValue val;
            val.irValue1 = irVal1;
            val.irValue2 = irVal2;
            this.Add(srKey, val);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will compile, but not actually change the value in the dictionary... Your change makes this a no-op.

Comment: But it also reveals *why* C# doesn't let you do this :)

Comment: Reed, that's absolutely NOT TRUE. There's only one copy of the object in memory.

Comment: @Diego Not with a struct.  Try it, this will not work.  You will never change the struct values once you add it using this code.  In order for this to work, `MyValue` would have to be a class (reference type), not a struct (value type), as value types have copy semantics.

Comment: @Diego In the original post - first line of code contains `public struct MyValue` - that's the entire problem here.  If it was a class, the OP's code would actually have worked without a compiler complaint.

Answer (score 1):

C# won't let you do this because `MyValue` is a struct.

The `this[...]` method will return a copy of the data, so if you change the field it won't do anything.

Change it to be a class instead.

If you *really* need it to be a struct, you can do this:

```
var tmp = this[srKey];
tmp.irValue1 += irVal1;
this[srKey] = tmp;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I modified the question and added class version. Would that work well ? or are there any better approach ?

Answer (score 1):

When using the indexer you are actually getting a copy of your `MyValue` since it is a struct type. The compiler is actually helping you here considerably by letting you know that the code is not doing what you expect. To resolve this issue you need to directly assign a new value.

```
var current = this[srKey];
this[srKey] = new MyValue { 
    irValue1 = current.irValue1 + irVal1, 
    irValue2 = current.irValue2 + irVal2 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a custom Dictionary, you need to inherit from `IDictionary <int, MyValue>` and implement the interface, Add(), Remove(), etc.